# Magento backup wont work

Tags: magento, backup

i have a problem with taking magento backup (both system, database and db + media backup). When taking backup everything seems to be working, but when finished the backup does not appear on the backup site or Var/backup.
First i tought the problem was memory limit since the webshop is big, but increasing the memory limit to 256m didnt solve the problem (http://dreamaquarium.no/nettbutikk/php.ini)

I was also thinking the problem was permissions in the backup folder, but does not seems like that is the problem (what permission should i use?). 
When i accessed the backup folder i found a .htaccess with the following content: deny from all. I deleted the .htaccess, and ran a backup - and it didnt seem to fix the problem.

Sooo any suggestions how to make the backup work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had the same problem with my magento shop. The the reason was a combination of to low memory limit and execution time.

So i suggest you to do the following: 
max_execution_time = 360;
memory_limit = 512M

Also set max_allowed_packet to 500M in my.ini/my.cnf fil under[mysqld] .

Regards, S.T